# Showing a function is square integrable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to show that the dirac delta function is in $H^{\frac{-n}{2}- \epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \forall \epsilon > 0.$ Where $H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ denotes Sobolev space of order $s$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

I have that since $\hat\delta = 1 \Rightarrow <\xi>^{s}\hat\delta = <\xi>^{s}$ trivially.

So this amounts to needing to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} |(1+|\xi|^{2})^{\frac{s}{2}}|^{2}d \xi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}, s= -\frac{n}{2} - \epsilon.$

But now I'm stuck. I know I need to show that this integral is finite.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Polar coordinates...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I had an attempt not sure if it's right. Rewriting the integral as

$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|(1+|\xi|^{2})^{\frac{s}{2}}|^{2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|(r^{2})^{\frac{s}{2}}|^{2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}r^{2s}dr $ but then I'm not sure how to evaluate this (if this is even correct).

Comment: @VBACODER: The integral with respect to $r$ should be on $(0,\infty)$, not $\Bbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Find a book on real analysis. If $f(x)=g(|x|)$ then $\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x)\,dx=c_n\int_0^\infty g(r) r^{n-1}\,dr$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich any recommendations for books that will have this in? I have the Folland book. 

Using the result in your comment, how would one proceed to get the result? 

If i integrate by parts i obtain $g(r) \frac{r}^{n}{n}|_{0}^{\infty}$ $ - \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} r^{n}g'(r)dr$

Comment: You have Folland but you couldn't look in the _index_ for "polar coordinates". Fine. Corollary 2.51.